# Android HttpClient .htaccess authentication

Tags: java, android, .htaccess, authorization, httpclient

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I'm trying to download a txt file from my apache web server. It has pretty basic authentication defined via .htaccess, such that I can log in with a simple `http://username:password@ipaddress/dir/file.txt` in my browser. However, this method returns the source code of my 403 page in HttpClient. How can I log in with this type of authentication? Also, I'd like it if I could do something more secure than that if I could. Thanks.

Edit: Current code below

```
URI url = new URI("http://username:password@ipaddress/dir/file.txt");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code, which you would possibly need to adjust to your needs:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

StringBuilder authentication = new StringBuilder().append("username").append(":").append("password");
String result = Base64.encodeBytes(authentication.toString().getBytes());

httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + result);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: "The method encodeBytes(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64" Also, what are the "nameValuePairs" and "is" variables?